# Is it OK to post an example question to multiple Area51 proposals?

Tags: discussion, area-51, example-questions

There are two proposals on Area51 which I am interested in, particularly because I believe that they provide a nice way of segmenting a field. Would it be acceptable to post the same questions to both to illustrate or test the delineation between the two? And is there a way I should indicate the duplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it OK to post an example question to multiple Area51 proposals?

If it's on-topic (or blatantly off-topic) on each proposal: Sure, absolutely!

> And is there a way I should indicate the duplication?

I'd say "no" in the defining stage of a site, which is all about finding out which questions are suitable and which are not. Whether a question is featured on another site is meaningless at this point.

"Yes" on a live site to avoid pissing off people who take the time to actually answer your question.

Comment: I would say no to blatantly off-topic. That way I could post a question about anything everywhere - do it, if you like to be down-voted.

Comment: Shall we say illustratively off topic? Since on-topic and off-topic are both essentially upvotes and bad example is the downvote.

Comment: @Ralph @Bell there are three votes: `Great on-topic example`, `great off-topic example`, and `not a good example`. By "blatantly off-topic" I mean the second category. What you @Ralph mean would be falling in the "not a good example" category

Comment: Yes, but good off topic questions aren't blatantly off-topic, they're subtly off topic.